# Regex: In a rule between 3 and 11 alphanumeric characters, how to limit between 0 and 3 digits

Tags: javascript, regex, digits, letter

In a rule between 3 and 11 alphanumeric characters, how to limit between 0 and 3 digits anywhere in the value ?

I try this regex `^(?=.*\d{0,3})([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,11})$` but it do't work.

Matches examples:

```
AnExample01
1Hello2
123World
```

Don't matches examples :

```
ThisValuedontWork1234
12Hello34
Hello12-World$34
```

Thanks !

Comment: Replace `(?=.*\d{0,3})` with `(?!(?:\D*\d){4})` - i.e. no more than 3 digits allowed in the string.